# Checkboxes VS Buttons

Tags: vba, excel

Please find the following workbook  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69651453/fff.xlsm  , is there a way we can instead use checkboxes? In the sense that one can de-check and the copied rows for that button are deleted and the gap closed again?

Also is there a way to disable check-boxes, depending on values in the sheet. In our case, if ANY invalid data is detected in the sheet, the checkboxes are greyed out... or blocked somehow.

Any Active X solutions would be appreciated too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use checkboxes and bind them to that specific cell then treat the cell's click event as you are the button click event it should function the same way.